# How to upgrade to php version 5.4.8 in Xampp?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I had searched but i could not get the proper guide. I had got the guide but there are no guide for 5.4.8 version. As per http://hype-free.blogspot.in/2007/07/updating-php-in-xampp-for-windows.html i did not have the php5apache_2.dll in the D:\xampp\apache\modules nor in \bin . Plz provide a solution. I am using xampp version 1.7.7 , php 5.3.8 and apache 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option :

- take backup of `htdocs` and `mysql` from current Xampp
- stop Apache and Mysql services and  Uninstall Current Xampp
- install new [`XAMPP 1.8.1`](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) which have **MySQL 5.5.27** , **PHP 5.4.7** and **phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2**
- then you can upgrade PHP version **5.4.8** , download **[Windows binaries](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4)**

Comment: did u mean download new Xampp